Mapping Microsoft EllipticalArcTo to Canvas ellipse
I am doing the function of Microsoft visio file parsing to the web canvas. When compatible with the attributes of EllipticalArcTo, I do not know how to map the EllipticalArcTo to the ellipse method of canvas. Their parameters are different. I am also not sure what the control point of EllipticalArcTo mentioned in visio's official website refers to specifically. I think my geometric ability is relatively weak. I would be grateful if you could provide me with any help.
Microsoft Visio EllipticalArcTo document
Canvas ellipse document
I've tried using Bessel curves to fit, but it doesn't seem to work very well

May be article Visio EllipticalArcTo can helps?

Other than that, check out this http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=880.0 and this https://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=2464.0
